# Como colocar en vista de blade los resultados json de guzzlehttp?

Tags: json, laravel-5, http, laravel-blade

He estado varias horas ya leyendo documentacion, he investigando como sacar los datos de la consulta http hecha con guzzle pero no logro solucionarlo. Necesito un poco de ayuda de como se debe dar formato a la respuesta recibida. Deseo tratar el string como Json, no como XML. Aprecio si alguien me colabora con esto. Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.3.29.
Aqui esta el codigo de lo que estoy haciendo.

Esto esta en mi controlador

```
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=76140,us&APPID=5a66d84bcde9e22f0907fe5e52917649', [
        'param_form'=>[]
    ]);
    $restful_data=$res->getBody()->getContents();
    $posts=Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    $view = View::make('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts])->with('restful_data',$restful_data);

    return $view;
```

Quiero imprimir por ahora todo solo para probar, o parte de lo que llega.
Esto en mi blade

`<p>{{$restful_data}}</p>`

Y esto es lo que veo llega de la consulta http

```
{"coord":{"lon":-97.29,"lat":32.63},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":298.84,"pressure":1006,"humidity":61,"temp_min":297.15,"temp_max":300.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":6.2,"deg":120,"gust":10.3},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1490735700,"sys":{"type":1,"id":2624,"message":0.0081,"country":"US","sunrise":1490703650,"sunset":1490748435},"id":4689708,"name":"Everman","cod":200}
```

Y el error que tengo al llamar la ruta.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in postController.php line 40: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
in postController.php line 40
```

Comment: ¿Algún motivo para no usar el helper `view()`? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-view

Comment: Hola @Shaz. Si con view si funciona. Solo que crei debia llevar make. No tengo mucha experiencia con esto aun. Gracias

Comment: Debieras hacer `$restful_data = json_decode( $res->getBody()->getContents(), true);`, de lo contrario estarás alimentando tu vista con un string

Comment: Si @amenadiel, ahi me funciona.. probe con lon y me da el numero -97.29. Gracias !!!. Quedo asi. $restful_data[]=json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
return view('dashboard',['posts'=>$posts])->with(['restful_data'=>$restful_data[0]['coord']['lon']]);